# ¿Por que no me muestra el contenido de mi pagina web 000webhost?

Tags: php, mysql, mvc, .htaccess

Ya tengo terminado un miniproyecto, funciona perfecto en mi pc "Localhost" pero cuando lo quiero subir a 000webhost se sube todo bien, pero al momento de querer ver una vista no la muestra, pero no aparece ningún error. Creo que es el .htaccess o el index.php Ayuda!!.

El modelo que sigue mi pagina es MVC.

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#Activar rewrite
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 https://stevencoailazaa.000webhostapp.com/error

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?controller=$1&action=$2
</Ifmodule>
```

Index.php

```
<?php


session_start();
require_once 'autoload.php';
require_once 'config/db.php';
require_once 'config/parameters.php';
require_once 'helpers/utils.php';

require_once 'views/layout/header.php';


function show_error() {
    $error = new errorController();
    $error->index();
}

if (isset($_GET['controller'])) {
    $nombre_controlador = $_GET['controller'] . 'Controller';
} elseif (!isset($_GET['controller']) && !isset($_GET['action'])) {
    $nombre_controlador = controller_default;
} else {
    show_error();
    exit();
}

if (class_exists($nombre_controlador)) {
    $controlador = new $nombre_controlador();

    if (isset($_GET['action']) && method_exists($controlador, $_GET['action'])) {
        $action = $_GET['action'];
        $controlador->$action();
    } elseif (!isset($_GET['controller']) && !isset($_GET['action'])) {
        $action_default = action_default;
        $controlador->$action_default();
    } else {
        show_error();
    }
} else {
    show_error();
}

require_once 'views/layout/footer.php';

?>
```

Imagen del proyecto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ProductoController.php

```
<?php

require_once 'models/producto.php';

class productoController {

    public function index() {
        $producto = new Producto();
        $productos = $producto->getRandom(6);

        require_once 'views/producto/destacados.php';
    }

    public function ver() {
        if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
            $id = $_GET['id'];

            $producto = new Producto();
            $producto->setId($id);

            $pro = $producto->getOne();   
        } 
        require_once 'views/producto/ver.php';
    }

    public function gestion() {
        Utils::isAdmin();

        $producto = new Producto();
        $productos = $producto->getAll();
        require_once 'views/producto/gestion.php';
    }

    public function save() {
        Utils::isAdmin();

        if (isset($_POST)) {
            $nombre = isset($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre'] : false;
            $descripcion = isset($_POST['descripcion']) ? $_POST['descripcion'] : false;
            $precio = isset($_POST['precio']) ? $_POST['precio'] : false;
            $stock = isset($_POST['stock']) ? $_POST['stock'] : false;
            $categoria = isset($_POST['categoria']) ? $_POST['categoria'] : false;
            //$imagen = isset($_POST['imagen']) ? $_POST['imagen'] : false;

            if ($nombre && $descripcion && $precio && $stock && $categoria) {
                $producto = new Producto();
                $producto->setNombre($nombre);
                $producto->setDescripcion($descripcion);
                $producto->setPrecio($precio);
                $producto->setStock($stock);
                $producto->setCategoria_id($categoria);

                //GUARDAR LA IMAGEN
                if (isset($_FILES['imagen'])) {
                    $file = $_FILES['imagen'];
                    $filename = $file['name'];
                    $mimetype = $file['type'];


                    if ($mimetype == "image/jpg" || $mimetype == "image/jpeg" || $mimetype == "image/png" || $mimetype == "image/git") {
                        if (!is_dir('uploads/images')) {
                            mkdir('uploads/images', 0777, TRUE);
                        }

                        move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], 'uploads/images/' . $filename);
                        $producto->setImagen($filename);
                    }
                }


                if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
                    $id = $_GET['id'];
                    $producto->setId($id);

                    $save = $producto->edit();
                } else {
                    $save = $producto->save();
                }


                if ($save) {
                    $_SESSION['producto'] = 'complete';
                } else {
                    $_SESSION['producto'] = 'failed';
                }
            } else {
                $_SESSION['producto'] = 'failed';
            }
        } else {
            $_SESSION['producto'] = 'failed';
        }
        header("Location:" . base_url . 'producto/gestion');
    }

    public function editar() {
        Utils::isAdmin();

        if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
            $id = $_GET['id'];
            $edit = true;

            $producto = new Producto();
            $producto->setId($id);

            $pro = $producto->getOne();

            require_once 'views/producto/editar.php';
        } else {
            header("Location:" . base_url . 'producto/gestion');
        }
    }

    public function eliminar() {
        Utils::isAdmin();

        if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
            $id = $_GET['id'];

            $producto = new Producto();
            $producto->setId($id);
            $delete = $producto->delete();

            if ($delete) {
                $_SESSION['delete'] = 'complete';
            } else {
                $_SESSION['delete'] = 'failed';
            }
        } else {
            $_SESSION['delete'] = 'failed';
        }
        header("Location:" . base_url . 'producto/gestion');
    }

}
```

autoload.php

```
<?php

function controllers_autoload($classname) {
    require_once 'controllers/' . $classname . '.php';
}

spl_autoload_register('controllers_autoload');
```

Comment: Añade `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors','on');` al inicio de index.php para ver que error se puede estar generando y muestra algún literal en la función de error, para saber que se pase por ahí en caso de error en blanco, algo como ` print_r( __ LINE __ );` te ayuda con el debug de las paginas (te mostrara el número de la linea que se ejecuta). NOTA: el __ LINE __ lleva doble guion bajo y sin espacios pero no puedo ponerlo porque este editor lo sustituye por negrita

Comment: OWWW me salieron 5 pero aqui no deja pasar imagen para que puedas ver

Comment: los veo en `https://stevencoailazaa.000webhostapp.com/`, pero, de todas formas, son texto y puedes copiar y pegar en la propia pregunta.

Comment: **Warning:** include(controllers/productoController.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /storage/ssd2/683/8232683/public_html/autoload.php on line 4

Comment: **Warning:** include(): Failed opening 'controllers/productoController.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /storage/ssd2/683/8232683/public_html/autoload.php on line 4

Comment: **Warning:** include(controllers/errorController.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /storage/ssd2/683/8232683/public_html/autoload.php on line 4

Comment: **Warning:** include(): Failed opening 'controllers/errorController.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /storage/ssd2/683/8232683/public_html/autoload.php on line 4

Comment: **Fatal error:** Uncaught Error: Class 'errorController' not found in /storage/ssd2/683/8232683/public_html/index.php:15 Stack trace: #0 /storage/ssd2/683/8232683/public_html/index.php(41): show_error() #1 {main} thrown in /storage/ssd2/683/8232683/public_html/index.php on line 15

Comment: ¿ves lo que está pasando?  No se cargan las librerías y por tanto no funciona nada. Cambia los `include_once()` por `require_once()`  así en vez de **Warning** te dará directamente **Error**  pues esas librerías son necesarias. Verifica las rutas y los permisos. Acostúmbrate a mostrar siempre los errores en desarrollo y en produccion ocultarlos pero sacarlos al log, el cual debes tener siempre a mano cuando actualizas o compruebas el funcionamiento.

Comment: Tienes un claro problema de divergencia en la forma en que usas los `include`.... ¿dónde se encuentra la carpeta `public_html` con respecto a las otras carpetas que muestras en la imagen?

Comment: Los nombres de archivo son *case sensitive*, es decir, no es lo mismo `productoController.php` que `ProductoController.php`, [aquí se puede ver que tus nombres de archivo empiezan con letra mayúscula](https://stevencoailazaa.000webhostapp.com/controllers/), pero en los `include` pones la primera letra en minúscula.  Por cierto, protege esas carpetas de miradas indiscretas, no es bueno que estén expuestas a navegación.

Comment: ya hice lo de cambiar de include_once() a require_once() pero eso de productoController.php a ProductoController.php no lo entiendo mucho

Comment: Hice una modificacion en <?php

define("base_url", "https://stevencoailazaa.000webhostapp.com/");
define("controller_default","ProductoController");
define("action_default","index"); Cambiando la P de producto a P mayuscula y ahora ya me muestra el titulo de la pagina DIRTER | DESTACADOS ya falta poco ayuda!!!

Comment: Ya me aparece el index!!!! pero ahora cuando quiero ingresar para logearme o registrarme me aparece este error ||||||| 
Warning: require_once(controllers/usuarioController.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /storage/ssd2/683/8232683/public_html/autoload.php on line 4

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'controllers/usuarioController.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /storage/ssd2/683/8232683/public_html/autoload.php on line 4

Comment: Como podria poner las controller y action la primera letra en Mayuscula. solo falta esto y todo estaria pero no se donde cambiarlo

Comment: jajajaj que feliz soy solo era cambiar el nombre de los Controller a minuscula de UsuarioController.php -> usuarioController.php GRACIAS CHICOS ME AYUDARON UN MONTÓN AHORA SI TENDRÉU UNA BUENA NOTA EN EL EXAMEN FINAL!!!!

Comment: puedes mostrar el contenido de tu archivo local composer.json?

Answer (score -1):

Para solucionar este problema solo tienes que cambiar el nombre de los archivos de la carpeta controllers. Su iniciar es Mayúscula, solo cámbiala a minúscula ejem: UsuarioController a usuarioController

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y por ultimo y mas importante en el autoload.php cambia el include_once() por require_once()

FORMA INCORRECTA

```
function controllers_autoload($classname) {
    include_once 'controllers/' . $classname . '.php';
}

spl_autoload_register('controllers_autoload');
```

FORMA CORRECTA

```
function controllers_autoload($classname) {
        require_once 'controllers/' . $classname . '.php';
    }

    spl_autoload_register('controllers_autoload');
```

Comment: No es que sea incorrecto hacerlo con `include()`  lo que sucede es que, en caso de no encontrar el fichero `include()` devuelve un **Warning** y continúa la ejecución, mientras que `require()` daría un **Error** y detendría el script. Depende del caso nos interesará una cosa u otra.  http://php.net/manual/es/function.include.php

Comment: esto es incorrecto si tratas de utilizar clases tanto los directorios como los nombres y los espacios de nombres de estos archivos deben iniciar con mayuscula, lo que debe cambiar son los datos del composer.json que se seguro estan mal declarados. si usan composer.json apeguence a las normas PSR y deje de estar inventando cosas que despues pueden dar mas problemas